# Is there a solution to connect a Web app to a Modbus PLCs

Tags: modbus, plc, modbus-tcp, industrial

I'm developing a Web application with HMI capabilities that needs to interface with multiple Modbus RTU and Modbus TCP PLCs:

- frequently update the web UI based on the state of the Modbus devices
- send commands to Modbus devices based on the user's input

What is the best way to integrate a Web application and a bunch of Modbus devices, given the requirements?

Comment: Have you tried googling [modbus library](https://www.google.com/search?q=modbus+library)?

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at [modbus bridges](https://www.dpstele.com/modbus/bridge.php) (or Modbus-RTU to Modbus-TCP converters)? and the 'middle-man' software we use at our place is [Kepware](https://www.kepware.com/en-us/products/kepserverex/) which then talks to our SCADA package ([Cimplicity](https://www.ge.com/digital/applications/hmi-scada/cimplicity) for us). Not sure if you're still in need of any more info on this, just shout back and i'll fill you in a lot more :)
Also, does this need to be a low cost solution (you could pretty much do this with off the shelf hobby hardware) or a full-blown industrial solution? Doing a dead simple SCADA bit and then talking to the plc's shouldn't pose too much of a headache if you have the time for it.